# how to transfer files from public instance to private instance using scp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I have one AWS private ec2 instance available in VPC. I also have one public subnet ec2 instance available in same VPC. I am able to connect to public instance using putty and as well as I am able to connect to private instance using Bastion host. Now my question is how can I transfer my code or some files to private ec2 instance .I am also able to ping my private instance from public instance. I tried to copy files from public instance to private ec2 instance, but it always gives public key error .Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
lost connection

Answer (score 0):

Since both instances are in the same VPC, then the connectivity between them should be in place, to achieve what you want do the following:

- SCP uses SSH, so make sure the Security group associated with the instance allow connection on port 22
- You also want to generate a public key from instance 1 and copy it to instance 2, so instance 2 can allow SSH connectoins (SCP command) from instance 1.

Comment: i am using this command scp ec2-user@publicip address :/home/userid/files/files.txt ec2-user@privateip:/home/ec2-user but i am getting error connection lost

Comment: You need to make sure that both instances has openssh-clients installed, connection lost means that your host instance is trying to establish an SSH connection(via SCP) with the remote instance but most likely the remote instance doesn't has SCP installed, try to install openssh-clients on the remote instance.